# Zend Framework 1 SQL query Where

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-table

Is there any way to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE p1=1 AND p2=2 AND ( p3 like %string1% OR p3 like %string3% )
```

In Zend Framework 1 by Zend_Db_Select or something else ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about how you would go about doing such complex nested query using Zend_Db_Select but you can write can consider writing query manually as follows -

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE p1 = ? AND p2 = ? AND (p3 LIKE ? OR p3 LIKE ?)';

$db->fetchAll($sql, [$p1, $p2, "%{$p3}%", "%{$p4}%"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should rather use [Zend_Db_Statement](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.statement.html), which gives flexible options for fetching result sets. You can use:

```
      $stmt = $db->query(
              'SELECT * FROM table WHERE p1 = ? AND p2 = ? AND (p3 LIKE ? OR p3 LIKE ?',
               array('1', '2', '%string1%', '%string3%')
              );
```